# How can I validade an image from its URL?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need to check if an image URL is valid, which means that the image loads properly in the browser.

I've tried using this:

```js
const src = "https://i.imgur.com/vXPYhT5.jpeg"
const img = new Image()

img.onload = () => console.log("valid image :)")
img.onerror = () => console.log("invalid image :(")

img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
img.src = src
```

The **problem** is that the above code outputs `"invalid image :("` in some mobile browsers e.g Safari, even when the image is valid.

To be more clear: the above code is not a cross browser solution for that problem.

Example of user agent this problem happened:

```
{
  "userAgentInfo": {
    "browserName": "Safari",
    "browserVersion": "13.0.5",
    "engineName": "AppleWebKit",
    "engineVersion": "605.1.15",
    "isBot": false,
    "isMobile": true,
    "os": "CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X",
    "platform": "iPhone"
  }
}
```

PS1: The image have all kind of CORS stuff enabled.

PS2: I can not see the error because its just a notification from the error tracker like `Airbrake.nofity("Invalid image")` on `img.onerror`.

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is here. Are you saying that `console.log` isn't logging anything in Mobile Safari? Do you know how to access the console in Mobile Safari in the first place?

Comment: What did you mean with URL validation? URL syntax, src availability ..

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I mean "the image loads properly in the browser". To be more specific: the `img.onload` callback fire.

Comment: @gedhean — It isn't any more clear. If you're logging to the console and can't see the console, then how is the code not working? Are you asking how to make it do something *other* than log to the console? If so, what do you want it to do and what problems are you having getting it to do that?

Comment: Re edit: I tested it in Mobile Safari. It outputs `valid image :)`

Comment: @Quentin -- I edited again. The problem is that the above code fire `onerror` when is suposed to fire `onload` in mobile Safari browser ( 
e.g. Safari 13.0.5).

Answer (score -1):

According to Mozilla CDN: The `Image()` constructor creates a new `HTMLImageElement` instance. It is functionally equivalent to `document.createElement('img')`.
See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

I have also checked the functionality is not working in Opera on my macOs! However, it is working on all other browsers. see this link:
https://jsbin.com/hofitusoke/edit?html,js,console,output

Moreover, for Browser compatibility, it is mentioned for some opera for mobile the functionality is unknown!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

some mobile browsers doesn't load image until it is place on DOM to reduce data consumption. So I don't have test device. But you can try this code.

```js
function validateImageUrl(url) {
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.onload = () => { console.log("valid image :)") }
  image.onerror = () => { console.log("invalid image :(") }

  image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
  image.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(image);
  image.src = url;

}

validateImageUrl('https://i.imgur.com/vXPYhT5.jpeg');
```

Comment: Could you provide the source of this information, please?

Comment: @gedhean did you test it on your device?

Comment: Actually, I do not have a device to test. The errors are being reported by an error tracker (third party service).

Comment: base idea is add an image tag to DOM. if this image doesn't show there is another problem. can you capture screen shot from error tracker? maybe you can use browserstack to wacth your code on test device enviroment.